# Class and id selectors not working in AntennaHouse Formatter

Tags: css, xml, print-css, antenna-house

I am new to Print CSS and am working on a template for an XML document, using AH Formatter Lite V6.6.
I cannot get class selectors to work.

For example, source snippet:

```
<section class="meta_Materials_(Structured)">
    <title>Materials</title>
    <para class="Body_Text">None.</para>
</section>
```

And template snippet:

```
.Body_Text{
    font-family:'HelveticaNeueLT Std LT';
    font-size:8.5pt;
    line-height:12pt;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style:normal;
    color: black;
}
```

... have no effect whatsoever.

The same applies to id selectors. I validated the template (passed), tried all sorts of equivalent selectors (para.Body_Text, section para.Body_Text, section > para.Body_Text), to no avail.

I cannot select any class or id anywhere in the document, though I can select elements.

What gives?

Comment: No takers, yet? The class and id selectors work as intended in Chrome and Edge. I also removed all styling from a document, and left only one class selector, but still no luck in AHF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the source document is XML, rather than HTML or XHTML, there is nothing special about the `class` attribute. To use the `class` attribute, you have to match on it or its value, just as you would for any other attribute:

```
*[class ~= "Body_Text"] {
    font-family:'HelveticaNeueLT Std LT';
    font-size:8.5pt;
    line-height:12pt;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style:normal;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!